# Parsing multipart request from Chrome

Tags: multipartform-data

I'm in the process of revamping a 20-year-old web application. One of the pieces of the application that has not been used in a long time is a file uploader. The Java servlet that parses the multipart upload includes the following code, that worked with all browsers long ago and still works with Firefox:

```
String boundary = "-----------------------------";            
   ServletInputStream in = req.getInputStream();              
   byte[] bytes = new byte[512];                              
   int state = 0;                                            
   ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   String name = null,                                        
          value = null,                                      
          filename = null,                                    
          contentType = null;                                
   Dictionary fields = new Hashtable();                      
                                                              
  //Read a line from the request input stream                    
     int i = in.readLine(bytes,0,512);                            
     while (-1 != i) {                                            
      String st = new String(bytes,0,i);                          
                                                                  
   //Beginning of parameter - write buffer from previous parameter
       if (st.startsWith(boundary)) {
```

This code does not work with Chrome, because Chrome starts its multipart/form-data boundary with "----WebKitFormBoundary" instead of "-----------------------------".

So I changed the servlet as follows:

```
String boundary = "-----------------------------";            
String boundary2 = "----WebKitFormBoundary";                  
   ServletInputStream in = req.getInputStream();              
   byte[] bytes = new byte[512];                              
   int state = 0;                                            
   ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   String name = null,                                        
          value = null,                                      
          filename = null,                                    
          contentType = null;                                
   Dictionary fields = new Hashtable();                      
                                                              
  //Read a line from the request input stream                    
     int i = in.readLine(bytes,0,512);                            
     while (-1 != i) {                                            
      String st = new String(bytes,0,i);                          
                                                                  
   //Beginning of parameter - write buffer from previous parameter
//       if (st.startsWith(boundary)) {                          
       if (st.startsWith(boundary) || st.startsWith(boundary2)) {  ​
```

The results have not changed.
Does anyone see anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With a packet sniffer, I found that, despite what it claims in the request headers, Chrome is actually starting its boundaries with "------WebKitFormBoundary" (note the two extra dashes at the beginning). I adjusted my code accordingly, problem solved.